# Flutter retrieve data in a List with FutureBuilder

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

at the moment im trying to understand some fundamentals of retrieving data with flutter and firestore. In my case I want to retrieve data once, so I decided to choose `FutureBuilder` instead of `StreamBuilder`.

Now when I place a print statement inside my widget tree I notice, that everytime I call my function of course the whole tree is rebuilding. Now I want to use a `Consumer`, so that only my `Listview.Builder` reloads, but i can't get it work propably. The widget tree ist still rebuilding. Hopefully someone can help me out.

```
Consumer<SongProvider>(builder: (context, sProvider, _) {
                  return FutureBuilder(
                      future: songFuture,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      

                          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                            case ConnectionState.none:
                            case ConnectionState.waiting:
                              return Align(
                                alignment: Alignment.center,
                                child: CircularProgressIndicator()
                              );
                            case ConnectionState.done:
                              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                                return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                              } else {

                                return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Text(
                                snapshot.data[index]['songName'].toString());
                          });
                              }
                          }

                          
                    }
                  );
            }))
      ],
    )));
  }
}
```

How can I make the `Consumer` work now? I think I need to replace it with the snapshots maybe, but i dont know how and where im getting the data from. please help

Comment: Consumer only work when your widget is under your provider, you can read more here: https://medium.com/flutter-community/understanding-provider-in-diagrams-part-1-providing-values-4379aa1e7fd5

Comment: Thank you for providing the source. I edited my code and I can assume that im using ChangenotifierProvider above my widget tree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a attribute for future as `Future<dynamic> yourDataFuture;` and initialize it in `initState` as

```
void initState() {
   super.initState();
   yourDataFuture= getData(); // get Data will returns a future
}
```

Then assign this variable as future to FutureBuilder as

```
...... rest of the code...

future: yourDataFuture,

....... rest of the code....
```

One more thing you need to handle **ConnectionStates** to prevent multiple calls. In your code, the future builder will call 3 times. one for `none`, 2nd time for `waiting` and third time for `done`.[Read](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ConnectionState-class.html). So, build the list when connection state reaches `done`

Comment: hey there, thank you for your code. i edited my question. I worked with the connection states, now it only loads when its done. Anyways how can I make the Consumer work now? I think I need to replace it with the snapshots maybe, but i dont know how and where im getting the data from. please help

Comment: For what purposes do you want to use Consumer?

Comment: I want to only rebuild the listviewbuilder if the data has changed instead of rebuilding the whole page

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/Consumer-class.html
you are not using consumer in a correct way. put your rest of the widget tree as a child of consumer and list inside the builder of the consumer. read the above link

Comment: I think its correct now, I implemented changenotifierprovider on the top of my app. now documentation tells that the consumer should be at the nearest possible position to the widget which has the data.Now we have to change snapshot.data[index]['songName'].toString()); to sProvider.foo.value . But I dont know if i also have to change all the snapshot vars too for example in the FutureBuilder builder: (context, snapshot) {} and I dont receive any values from db.getSongsOnce(); to get sProvider.foo.value